# How do I show only the rows based on the value in the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I show only the people in the department where kurt is in?

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table 
WHERE (name= 'kurt' OR department IN (select department from sample_table
where name = 'kurt'
group by department 
having count(*) > 1));
```

From this one:

| name | department |
| --- | --- |
| kurt | 2 |
| john | 1 |
| mark | 1 |
| rose | 2 |
| anna | 2 |

to this one:

| name | department |
| --- | --- |
| kurt | 2 |
| rose | 2 |
| anna | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    sample_table
WHERE
    department = (
        SELECT
            department
        FROM
            sample_table
        WHERE
            name = 'kurt'
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses exists logic:

```sql
SELECT s1.name, s1.department
FROM sample_table s1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sample_table s2
              WHERE s2.department = s1.department AND s2.name = 'kurt');
```

Comment: I didnt even know the EXISTS clause. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Answer as below

```
SELECT
    name, department
FROM
    sample_table
where
    department in (
        select distinct department
    from
        sample_table
    where
        name = 'kurt')
```

This will return even when kurt is in many departments